# How does the binding work in WPF/XAML?

Tags: wpf, xaml, mvvm

How does the binding work in xaml when we mention a property name even if the property doesn't exist, the code doesn't break, how and why is that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

WPF swallows binding exceptions. If you run with the debugger attached and look at your output window, you will see error messages being traced for binding failures.

Comment: Yes thats right I do see binding errors, but if I am missing a property is it wrong? like any impact on performance or something? and why does it swallows, on one side it helps with loose coupling because of this but at the same time there are exceptions in the background when the property doesn't exist.

Comment: @NSingla Swallowing exceptions was a design decision made by the WPF team - this is just the way it works. If you have a binding that is failing then you have an issue with your program (although the issue can obviously range in its seriousness).